# Raid1+0: create stripe over two /dev/mdx on partition or not?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm, md

Given that I haven't found a way to define how a Raid10 is created with mdadm, i went the Raid1+0 solution.

[How to display/define Mirror/Stripping pairs with mdadm](https://serverfault.com/questions/599137/how-to-display-define-mirror-stripping-pairs-with-mdadm)

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdf1
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1
mdadm --create /dev/md10 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0 /dev/md1
```

My question is about the stripe. For the mirror I create a primary partition over the full HD and set partition type to FD.

So, should I do the same for the Stripe? Create partition on /dev/md0 and /dev/md1 (primary over full 'HDD', set partition type correctly) and then do the stripe on the partition?

Is there a correct way here or are there any advantages/disadvantages to a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use the full block devices of `md0`/`md1` - the partition's not really helping anything.

But why not just do one device with `--level=10` (assuming you're running new enough code to have that support)?

Comment: I can't use the Raid10 functionality because I need to specify what HDDs are mirrored (see link on top, its another question)